Как сторонние сайты получают доступ к Instagram-аккаунтам?
Есть подобные сайты, как этот, которые выводят всю информацию из указанного Instagram-аккаунта. Как такие сайты получают доступ к данным? API-ключ для таких сайтов вряд ли дают.

"Подобные сайты" получают доступ именно благодаря API и соответствующим ключам, которые зачастую не просто платные, но ещё и достаточно дорогие, особенно у популярных сервисов или ради отдельных "плюшек". Несомненно есть ещё способ обычного парсинга информации, но как правило овчинка выделки не стоит ибо это не только сложнее, но и не исключает ситуации, что рано или поздно твой парсер будет выловлен и заблокирован. Но куда чаще можно столкнуться с тем, что формат вывода изменится и вам снова придётся ковырять свой парсер.
